# How to Add space between 2 pictures in office interop word c#?

Tags: c#, office-interop, desktop-application, word-automation

im trying to add two pictures no matter what i do they will be placed on each other
so how to add these two pictures exactly **under** each other with **specified space** in between?

```
  //first picture

      wrdRng = oDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
            string imagename = "C:\\Users\\a_shi\\Desktop\\Man\\madarek\\man3.jpg";
            InlineShape pictureShape = wrdRng.InlineShapes.AddPicture(imagename);
            pictureShape.Width = 150;
            pictureShape.Height = 150;
            Word.Shape shape = pictureShape.ConvertToShape();
            shape.WrapFormat.Type = Word.WdWrapType.wdWrapInline;
            shape.Left = (float)Word.WdShapePosition.wdShapeCenter;
            shape.Top = (float)Word.WdShapePosition.wdShapeTop;
//what ive tried so far
            wrdRng.InsertParagraphAfter();
            wrdRng.InsertAfter("\v");

//second picture

    wrdRng = oDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
                string pa = "C:\\Users\\a_shi\\Desktop\\some stuff\\wow.jpg";
                InlineShape pictureShape = wrdRng.InlineShapes.AddPicture(pa);
                pictureShape.Width = 100;
                pictureShape.Height = 150;
                Word.Shape shape1 = pictureShape.ConvertToShape();
                shape1.WrapFormat.Type = Word.WdWrapType.wdWrapSquare;
                shape1.Left = (float)Word.WdShapePosition.wdShapeCenter;
              shape1.Top = (float)Word.WdShapePosition.wdShapeTop
```

and how to add certain space (empty line) after any element in office interop word?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When theres nobody to help you... **HELP YOURSELF**! thats what im gonna do:

So assume you wanna add space between 2 elements in office interop word, just follow the 3 steps below and you will do just fine:

1)Define a new *Range* and set it to end of doc:

```
object newrng1 = oDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
```

2)Add a new paragraph to the range we just defined. (even if theres no content!) we do this to use *ParagraphFormat* property.

```
Word.Paragraph oPara = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref newrng1);
```

3)finally add the desired space, note that the **LineSpacing** property only accepts float.

```
 oPara.Range.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = 20.0f;
```